# how to write this function in more concise manner in python

Tags: python, function

The beauty of `python` is often reflected in its simplicity and one-liner codes.
I am slowly getting myself in writing them.
I have a function that calculates the `sum  of n` powers of 2.

ex: `if n==4, I get 2^4+2^3+2^2+2^1+2^0`
I have this function which works fine, but wondering if there is room for condensing to one or two lines

```
>>> def sumpowers(n):
...    sum=0
...    for x in range(n+1):
...       sum+=pow(2,x)
...    return sum
... 
>>> sumpowers(31)
4294967295
```

Any tips or some use of `built-ins` that can improve it in terms of simplicity?

Thanks

Comment: Mathematically you have also `sum = pow(2,n+1) - 1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using `reduce built-in` and lambda, you could achieve it:

```
>>> reduce(lambda x,y: x+y, [pow(2,i) for i in range(32)])
4294967295

in terms of function:
try this:
    >>> def test(n):
...    return reduce(lambda x,y: x+y,[pow(2,i) for i in range(n+1)])
... 
>>> test(31)
4294967295
```

EDIT: using `reduce` is absolutely not necessary. as pointed out in the comments, it might not often be a good idea. but it is an aspect of functional programming that could be made of use and is one of several ways pointed out

Comment: what does the `reduce` too?

Comment: `operator.add` is preferred over `lambda x, y: x + y`. Also, you could change the list comprehensions to generator expressions, saving memory.

Comment: @sweeneyrod: yes absolutely. you are spot-on. There are multiple ways this could be acheived, since `sum` is posted, I am doing the `reduce` version.

Comment: @eagertoLearn `operator.mul(2, 3) == 6`. `reduce(operator.mul, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] == 1*2*3*4*5`.

Comment: REDUCE the use of reduce. Why make it more complicated? (Guido Van Rossum is always unhappy to see when somebody uses reduce!)

Comment: @Jack_of_All_Trades: any reason why he is unhappy?

Comment: @user1988876 He doesn't like functional programming in general, and he things reduce is quite difficult to read and often unnecessary, hence why it was moved to the `functools` module. I agree with him to some extent - in many cases (like this) you can use other functions like `sum`, and in more complicated situations, `reduce` is often unreadable.

Comment: Because it makes code much more complicated than it should be. Try to trace the output of reduce-used code in paper and you will know why? Code should be clear as possible not complicated.

Comment: @Jack_of_All_Trades: I agree with it, that it often makes it difficult to read. but in this simple example, I can follow it rather easily even on paper. moreover, its a good use here, as it is easy to follow and read..may be at higher levels, it might be difficult to follow

Comment: @user1988876 I think it is good at a level like this (for instance `reduce(operator.mul, range(1, x+1))` to calculate a factorial, but in this specific example (and indeed in all examples where you are reducing with addition) you should use `sum`.

Comment: It is worth mentioning than `reduce` was taken out of the builtins and is accessible from the `functools` module in Python 3.0.

Comment: @sweeneyrod: yes, ofcourse, but that does not mean `dont use it`, I believe the power of python over other languages is in its functional programming regime, which is again a matter of debate..thats just my perspective..

Answer (score 3):

That for-loop can be replaced with the [`sum`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#sum) built-in and a [generator expression](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/):

```
>>> def sumpowers(n):
...     return sum(pow(2,x) for x in range(n+1))
...
>>> sumpowers(31)
4294967295
>>>
```

You may also want to replace `pow(2,x)` with just `2**x`:

```
>>> def sumpowers(n):
...     return sum(2**x for x in range(n+1))
...
>>> sumpowers(31)
4294967295
>>>
```

Comment: what difference does it make: `2**x or pow(2,x)`

Comment: @eagertoLearn `pow` can take a third parameter for algebra on modulo-rest-classes Z/n. `pow` from `math` does not support complex parameters. The `**` operator does not take a third operand, but works for both floats and complex.

Comment: Also, `**` should be slightly faster than `pow`.

Answer (score 3):

Try the following:

```
def sumpowers(n):
    return ((2 ** (n+1)) - 1)
```

Comment: A closed form is almost always preferable.

Answer (score 2):

Try this solution, is more idiomatic:

```
def sumpowers(n):
    return sum(2**x for x in range(n+1))
```

The "trick" to make it more concise lies in using the following:

- A [generator expression](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions), instead of explicit looping
- The [`sum`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum) built-in function, instead of a counter variable
- The `**` operator, instead of the [`pow`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#pow) built-in function (the two are equivalent when using two arguments)

But wait! we can make things even simpler by using mathematical properties. The function is equivalent to this (with kudos to @fp for pointing it out first):

```
def sumpowers(n):
    return 2**(n+1)-1
```

Either way, it works as expected:

```
sumpowers(31)
=> 4294967295
```

Answer (score 2):

Nothing is better in this case than list comprehension.

```
my_sum=sum([2**x for x in range(n+1)])
```

Comment: Well, except for turning the list comprehension to a generator expression (remove the square brackets), saving memory and keystrokes.